# Same route hiding component issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-router, react-props

I have two different components that are rending under one another in my application because they have the same starting route. My current application flow goes from Booking to Time component using this:

```
<Link to={'/booking/' + this.props.booking.getURLName()} >
```

How can I make Booking component disappear when Time component appears?

```
<Router history={history}>
    <div>
        <IndexRoute exact path="/" component={Home} />
        <Route path='/booking' render={(props) => <Booking {...props} details={details} />}/>
        <Route path='/booking/:name' render={(props) => <Time {...props} details={details} />}/>
    </div>
</Router>

class Booking extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <Col>
                <Link to={'/booking/' + this.props.booking.getURLName()} >
                    <div>
                        // Booking details here
                    </div>
                </Link>
            </Col>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use switch from react router dom.

```
<Switch history={history}>
<div>
    <IndexRoute exact path="/" component={Home} />
    <Route path='/booking' render={(props) => <Booking {...props} details={details} />}/>
    <Route path='/booking/:name' render={(props) => <Time {...props} details={details} />}/>
</div>
</Switch>
```

Comment: I had to wrap Switch around BrowserRouter because it gave me an error saying You should not use <Switch> outside a <Router>

Comment: I got the same issue from it

Comment: Adding exact in my booking route fixed the issue. Should I add exact in both the booking routes?